# Random walk on infinite king's graph

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider the graph with $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a vertex set, and with an edge between two vertices iff their $L^{\infty}$-distance is $1$. Imagine we perform a random walk on this graph, starting at the origin.

Equivalently, imagine a chess king moving randomly on an infinite chessboard.

Does anyone know whether this process has been studied? I am particuarly curious as to whether there is some sort of asymptotical rotational invariance.

Comment: what is meant by rotational invariance, that it may have asymptotics? [It would seem there was some kind of count done for finitely many moves, for there to be asymptotics, along with some notion of rotational equivalence between individual items counted.]

Comment: The following claim is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Relation_to_Wiener_process: "...a Wiener process in several dimensions is the scaling limit of random walk in the same number of dimensions ... A Wiener process enjoys many symmetries a random walk does not. For example, a Wiener process walk is invariant to rotations, but the random walk is not, since the underlying grid is not (random walk is invariant to rotations by 90 degrees, but Wiener processes are invariant to rotations by, for example, 17 degrees too)."

(This isn't an answer, since I don't have a proof to cite.)

Comment: Look up random walk on a $d$-regular tree. In your case $d = 8$.

Comment: Thanks Chris Culter. That is what I meant by asymptotical rotational invariance, that there is some kind of limiting law that is rotational invariant. It might be Brownian motion, but I am not sure the claim in the wiki-article includes walks on non-planar graphs like the king's graph.

Michh, I will look up d-regular trees. My graph has cycles, so it is not a tree, would it apply anyway?

Comment: Oooh, I see. I knew how a king moves, and what $L^\infty$ means, but for some reason I was still imagining the ordinary lattice walk.

My impression is that your process probably also limits to Brownian motion, because a quick trip across Google makes it sound like everything does. Of course, that's not a real argument.